# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type

Tags: c#, json

У меня есть такой JSON:

```
{"success":true,"totalCount":7,"data":{"areagrafer":[],"login":"user123","name":"user","description":null,"roles":[],"id":1190740029004,"road":null},"settings":null,"type":null,"model_name":null}
```

Есть классы:

```
public class Data
 {
        public long[] Areagrafer { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string[] Roles { get; set; }
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public int? Road { get; set; }
   }

    public class ResponseRootSingle<T> 
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Когда я пытаюсь распарсить вот такой JSON:

```
{"success":true,"totalCount":1,"data":["No user with id = 1190740029003"],"settings":null,"type":null,"model_name":null}
```

```
 var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseRootSingle<Data>>(json);
```

То получаю ошибку:

> System.Exception: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Data' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы поле Data была null, вместо исключения?

Comment: а зачем генерик вам?

Comment: `"data":["No user with id = 1190740029003"],` - это массив из одного элемента?

Comment: @tym32167 да, туда записывается сообщение от сервера

Comment: А как вы этот массив собрались десериализовать в `Data`?

Comment: @tym32167 у меня десериализуется в Data вот этот JSON:                              {"success":true,"totalCount":7,"data":{"areagrafer":[],"login":"user123","name":"user","description":null,"roles":[],"id":1190740029004,"road":null},"settings":null,"type":null,"model_name":null} но от сервера может придти такой ответ: "data":["No user with id = 1190740029003"] и тогда получаю ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в настройки десериализации кастомный метод обработки ошибок ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988724/null-value-exception-thrown-when-deserializing-null-value-json-net)):

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseRootSingle<Data>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Error = HandleDeserializationError
});
```

Добавить метод:

```
private static void HandleDeserializationError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
{
    var currentError = e.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
    e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В указанной строке

```
{"success":true,"totalCount":1,"data":["No user with id = 1190740029003"],"settings":null,"type":null,"model_name":null}
```

У вас поле **Data** является типом **IEnumerable**
И JSON не может присвоить свойству с типом **Data** тип **IEnumerable**
Вам нужно либо десериализовать как

```
var answer = DeserializeObject<ResponseRootSingle<JToken>>(...)
```

и смотреть **answer.Data.IsArray** или нет и приобразовывать уже в нужный объект **JToken.ToObject<%ObjectType%>()**

Либо написать кастомный **ContractResolver**